# Cache issues with logged in users Magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-group, varnish

We're facing an annoying issue in Magento 2.2.5. We have customers that are attached to a customergroup with different prices. This is our scenario:

- User visits 2 or 3 categories and sees the regular prices
- User logs in into his account
- User visits same categories again, and **should see** the different prices but sees the old (cached) prices. After a hard-refresh the different prices are shown, but these should be shown right away.

We also faced this issue before on Magento 2.0.14. For caching we use Varnish.

Comment: What if you exclude the `catalog_product_price` from Varnish ?

Comment: I did not try this yet, I hope it works, how can I do this?

Comment: table exclude from varnish `catalog_product_price` ???

Comment: Can you post a quick how-to as answer? I think more people are looking for this kind of answer.

Comment: Would be great if you can help with this issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Seems silly that this issue even exists.